# Variable color for template multisite

Tags: php, typo3

I am a beginner in TYPO3 and I am currently integrating a template that can be used in multisite.

And now, I have to set up a color variable system that will allow different sites to have their color. For example I have to change the color of my navbar, currently I have a color defined by my css file.

I know that I must create constants in my `constants.ts` file which will be editable in the constant editor in the template tab
But I don't know how to go about it at all, can you give me some advice please? thank you

Comment: Please add the TYPO3 Version your using. It looks like your on a bit older version since your using the `*.ts` file ending.

Comment: Im on 10.4.17 version

Answer (score 0):

How to define TS-Constants can you find in the [manuals](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/UsingSetting/Constants.html), it is like any values in TypoScript.
You might have the Constant Editor in mind, where you can define a configuration for easier settings of values, which also is described in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/UsingSetting/TheConstantEditor.html).

If you only want to define some colours you can output them in the [TypoScript setup](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/9.5/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#cssinline-array):
**constant**:

```
# cat=content/mydef/col1; type=color; label= Highlight color for text
color1_from_const = #ff0000

# cat=content/mydef/col2; type=color; label= Highlight background color for text
color2_from_const = #ffffcc
```

**setup**:

```
page {
   cssinline {
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = .highlight { color:{$color1_from_const} }

      20 = TEXT
      20.value = .highlight2 { background-color:{$color2_from_const} }
   }
   :
}
```

---

If you want to compute a set of colours from given base colours (like: lighten or darken a color by 10%) you can use multiple ways:

- compute it in PHP
- compute it with LESS/SASS
- compute it inside of CSS

The first is possible as PHP can output anything. But the calculation is a little bit tricky.

The second is difficult as the compilation needs to take place after a new value is entered and it needs values in special files which needs to be compiled for the final output (there is no mechanism in TypoScript to write to files, which were processed before output)

The third could be possible, but is very new technology I have no experience yet and only is theoretical knowledge for me.

Comment: Thank you I was able to understand how to define the variables, however I do not see how to create color variables and insert them in my CSS, then be able to modify these colors thanks to the constant editor.

My problem is that I don't know how to target a CSS class from typoscript and manipulate this class by giving it the desired color.

Comment: CSS is no interactive language, you only can declare a rule. and afterward redeclare or override it. On the other hand CSS files normally are static. and you can't modify a file on the fly with TypoScript.